# ODE with solution in a subspace

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

The task is to show that if $A$ is a Markov matrix, as to say the sum of all the entries in $A$ for each column equal $0$ and all the entries $a_{ij} ≥ 0$ for $i\neq$j then the solution to the ODE $y'=Ay$ with starting value $x\in H$ always stays in $H$ or differently put $e^{At}H⊂H$ for all $t\in R$, where $H$ is defined as $H=(v \in R^n,\sum v_i=c\in R)$ so when one sums up the entries of the vector, one gets a constant c.

This is an exercise from Amman-Escher Analysis II

Comment: Seems awfully wrong, consider A=I.

Comment: sorry I misread the exercise, correcting it now, what is wrong is that $A$ isn't a Markov matrix, but is actually stated as one, weird...

Comment: Not so weird, simply a mix up between transition matrices in discrete time (which have sums 1) and kernels in continuous time (which have sums 0).

Comment: weird in the sense that it isn't one, but is stated as one. Also I have no bloody clue what you're talking about, since this is an exercise for freshman year mathematicians..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this claim is false, try a matrix $A=(1)$, the solution to the ODE is $y(t)=y(0)e^t$, which clearly changes over time.

If you write the differential equation satisfied by the sum of entries in your $y$, you obtain

$$\frac{d}{d t}\sum_j y_j(t) = \sum_j y_j(t),$$
which leads to

$$\sum_j y_j(t) = e^t \left(\sum_j y_j(0)\right).$$

**Edit**

After a correction (now $\sum_j A_{ij}=\sum_i A_{ij}=0$ instead of $1$), the problem became obvious. As previously, we write a differential equation on  $\sum_j y_j(t)$. It's easy to prove that

$$\frac{d}{d t}\sum_j y_j(t) =0,$$
which guarantees that the sum of components of $y$ remains constant.

**Second edit**

We write
$$y_i'(t)=\sum_j A_{ij}y_j(t), $$
then take a sum with respect to $i$ of both sides:
$$\sum_i y_i'(t)=\sum_i\sum_j A_{ij}y_j(t)=\sum_j\sum_i A_{ij}y_j(t) = \sum_j\left(y_j(t)\sum_i A_{ij}\right) = \sum_j 0.$$

Comment: corrected, the matrix that is stated isn't a Markov matrix eventhough it is stated as one, which led to confusion on my part

Comment: please tell me how you get from the stated matrix equation $\sum_{i=1}^n y'_i(t) e_i = \sum_{i,j=1} a_{i,j} y_j(t) e_i$ to your conclusion? I can't seem to cancel anything out as I have to not only sum over the colums, but I also multiply them with a unknown function y_j, I may be acting stupid so just give me a hint

Comment: Edited my answer.